# npm command not found after restart

Tags: macos, node.js, terminal, npm

The `npm` command keeps becoming unrecognised after a computer restart:

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

The `node` command still works fine, it's just `npm` that's not working. I have to reinstall Node.js from the main site to get it working again.

`~/bin` is added to my `$PATH` in my `.bash_profile` with:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

**Edit:** I'm also using the full [mathiasbynens/dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) which manages its own version, I wonder if there's a conflict here.

Comment: same problem here! i use nvm as installer

Answer (score 9):

According to [nvm readme file](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), try to run this once:

```
nvm alias default stable
```

This will set a default Node version to be used in any new shell.

Comment: This even solved an issue with clasp (which is installed via npm) being not found within VSCode terminals.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

I have no explanation, but a few pointers:

As @LaurentPerrin states, `node` (via its *official* installer package) installs to `/usr/local/bin`.
(Why do you mention `~/bin`?)

<sup>Note that different rules apply if you use *user-level* installs via node.js version manager **[nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)**, in which case [symlinks to] executables are placed in `~/.nvm/v{version}/bin`</sup>

Thus, the `node` executable should be `/usr/local/bin/node`.

Is this (only) what you see when you run `which -a node`?

The `node` executable is placed *directly* in `/usr/local/bin`, whereas `npm` is merely a *symlink* that points to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`, which is an executable node script with shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

When you run

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm
```

you should see something like

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  38 Dec 13 11:52 /usr/local/bin/npm -> \
                                           ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

See if the symlink exists and points to the right file.

If that still doesn't work, try to invoke `npm-cli.js` directly and see what happens (this should show npm's command-line help):

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js help
```

Answer (score 2):

On OSX, node is installed to `/usr/local/bin`, which needs to be in your path. Edit `/edit/paths` as root (`sudo nano /etc/paths`) and make sure it is on the first line. It should look like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Then you can force bash to refresh paths by running: `source /etc/profile`.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` was already in this file, though at the bottom of the list. I moved it to the top, saved and refreshed paths but still `npm` is not working.

Comment: Which node version do you have?

Comment: 0.10.21 which includes `npm`. I keep having to reinstall to get npm to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem (on OSX). Not sure if this is the solution for you, but I ended up finding npm here:

```
.nvm/v0.10.22/bin
```

or, based on your version

```
.nvm/v0.10.21/bin
```

Then I just printed my working directory and added that to my path. So for me, when I opened terminal:

```
cd .nvm/v0.10.22/bin
pwd
>> /path/to/.nvm/v0.10.22/bin
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What you're describing assumes use of `node.js` via the version manager `nvm` (https://github.com/creationix/nvm). `nvm` modifies your shell profile to source `~/.nvm/nvm.sh`, which in turn adds its active `node.js` version - e.g. `~/.nvm/v0.10.22` - to your `$PATH`.

Comment: You need to tell nvm which version of node to use. You can either set a default for it to automatically use (whenever you open terminal) using `nvm alias default version`. So in your case `nvm alias default 0.10.22`. Or just use `nvm use 0.10.22` on each Terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

I use nvm to install node.js. I solve it by adding `$HOME/.nvm/v0.10.25/bin` to `$PATH`. So the problem is that the path can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My solution is use `sudo ...`. My guess this is because of the permission problem.