# Node and npm not found after restarting macOS

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I am using my corporate's laptop and am a new mac User (used Ubuntu before) :

- OS: macOS Monterey Version 12.2

There are two accounts, administrator and mine - I don't have sudo rights. To install homebrew without administrator rights, I followed [this Installation](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere).

To install the node - I used `brew install node`. Both `node -v` and `npm -v` were working. When I restarted the laptop, I cannot find node/npm.

On running `$ node -v`, I get `-bash: node: command not found` (I changed my default terminal from zsh to bash and the output is the same for both of them)

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30950343/10217754) but couldn't find nvm in the system. Am new to mac and I believe nvm is some kind of package manager like homebrew so this solution is not applicable to me (correct me if I am wrong).

How can I install things in my system without sudo rights and keep them permanently(like node)?

EDIT:

- (After adding brew to the PATH) On running - `brew list|grep node`, I got - `node`
- `$ echo $PATH` gives `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/parthkapadia/homebrew/bin`

EDIT2:

- Adding brew to path solved the issue, now I can even access node and npm (even after restarting). I used [this](https://wpbeaches.com/how-to-add-to-the-shell-path-in-macos-using-terminal/) site to add homebrew/bin to path  (in zsh terminal)

Comment: Try `brew list | grep node` to ensure brew thinks node is installed and `brew --prefix node` to see where it thinks the binary is.

Comment: Run `echo $PATH` to check that your PATH has not been mangled. If it has, fix your shell startup scripts.

Comment: Per those instructions you used, it looks like `brew` is installed in `~/homebrew` possibly under the `bin` subfolder so you need to add that to your PATH. To do it temporarily, use `PATH=~/homebrew/bin:$PATH` and then re-run the earlier `brew` commands. To permanently add `~/homebrew/bin` to your PATH, add it in your shell startup scripts (you can search for how to do that if you don't know). Also research `shellenv.sh` that was installed with brew.

Comment: @jarmod Followed https://wpbeaches.com/how-to-add-to-the-shell-path-in-macos-using-terminal/ and added homebrew/bin to path, now running brew works, Thanks

Comment: yea your path looks broken.

Comment: @DanielA.White why? I have edited the ques, looks like adding brew to the path has solved the issue, anything else looks incorrect?

Comment: its smushed here - `:/Users/parthkapadia/homebrew/bin`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was homebrew's path. It was not added to the PATH variable.
When I restarted the system, homebrew was no longer in the PATH (as it was temporarily added probably when I installed it). As homebrew was not added to PATH, the terminal didn't recognize `brew` or any package installed using it like `node` or `npm`.

I solved it by adding `Users/username/homebrew/bin` to `PATH`. The steps I followed are -

- `cd` - to move to the home directory
- `touch .zshrc` to create .zshrc file as it didn't exist
- `nano .zshrc` to open the file for editing
- Added `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/yourusername/homebrew/bin` in the file (this appends homebrew/bin to the PATH variable)

Now the terminal can recognize brew and hence node and npm too.
Refer [this](https://wpbeaches.com/how-to-add-to-the-shell-path-in-macos-using-terminal/) for more detailed explanation on how to add to PATH in macOS.

Thanks to all the people who helped in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to get Node and npm **with Nvm**, and encounter this issue, I hope this will help you a bit.

I used NVM (Node Version Manager) to get node. After restarting the mac, I found out that Node and npm were missing.

I came to the conclusion that I had to **install Xcode (manually from the App Store) first**. It is also mentioned at [NVM's documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

After installing Xcode, I used the command `homebrew doctor` to see if everything is fine. I had to change the Xcode path, using this command `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app;`. I guess I wouldn't have to do it if I had installed homebrew **after** getting Xcode from the app store.

So finally, I did install NVM again using this command `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash` and everything worked fine.

Comment: You write "this didn't work for me", specify what (exter's answer). Do not assume the order of answer on StackOverflow stays, it can change according to user preference and answer score.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for that! I will make sure to edit my comment.